What is the canonical action of a groupoid on its unit space?
Supposedly, a groupoid $G$ acts canonically on its unit space $G^{(0)}$. What is this action explicitly?
I think this is the action where an arrow takes its source unit element to the target/range of the arrow. Then this is not a group action but a groupoid action? What is a groupoid action? In a group action, each element of the group induces a homemorphism on the $G$-space but in the groupoid case, this is never the case.
I have also read that one can form a transformation groupoid out of this canonical action. But I have only seen the definition of a transformation groupoid for a group action. So what does the transformation groupoid of a groupoid action look like?
The set of all bisections of a groupoid also canonically acts on the unit space. What is this action? All my groupoids are étale.

https://planetmath.org/groupoidaction

@AnneBauval that definition is poorly written. For example, they talk about a map $\mu$ and then go on to not impose any condition on it.

Exel's paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703182 will help you to solve your last question "The set of all bisections of a groupoid also canonically acts on the unit space. What is this action?".
As you write, the set of all all bisections of a groupoid acts on the unit space. More precisely, the set of all (open) bisections of an ('etale) groupoid $G$ forms an inverse semigroup and this inverse semigroup acts on the unit space $G^{(0)}$. The definitions of these notions are written in Example 5 in pp.20 of the above Exel's paper.
Remark that a bisection is called a slice in Exel's paper.
